# Cannot get a Bokeh checkbox group to update graph

Tags: python, jupyter, bokeh

I am trying to create a simple interactive graph with a checkbox group. I want the checkboxes to result in showing the appropriate line on the graph when ticked. I am doing this within Jupyter Notebook.

I've managed to get it embedded in Jupyter, and I wrote a callback function that does execute code. I am able to create a new ColumnDataSource from the checkbox selection. However, the graph is just not updating.

I've gone through every post on here I could, and look at every tutorial I could find. Most of them simply have an update callback which creates the new source, then sets the graph's source to the new one, which I believe is supposed to update the graph. I have also seen variations where people assign it as oldsource.data = newsource.data. This doesn't work for me either.

I am wondering whether there is any inherent limitations in embedding to Jupyter Notebook that I need Javascript for, or limitations to how sources can be updated. Or maybe I am just missing something very obvious? Code below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bk
import bokeh.layouts as ly
import bokeh.models as md
import bokeh.colors as cl
import bokeh.palettes as plet
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.io import show as io_show
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Select, Button
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, show, figure, output_notebook, reset_output, curdoc

data_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
data_list2 = ["one", "two"]
data_fac = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
data_fac_dict = dict(zip(data_list,data_fac))
data_x = np.linspace(0,100)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = data_list)

def modify_doc(doc):

    def make_data(data_list):
    #Make new source with appropriate datasets
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns = data_list)

        for case in data_list:
            df[case] = data_x * data_fac_dict[case]

        result = md.ColumnDataSource(df)

        return result

    #Make colors
    list_colors = plet.Dark2[len(data_list)]
    dict_colors = dict(zip(data_list,list_colors))

    #Default source with one datapoint
    src = make_data(["one"])

    print(src.data.keys())

    #Plot graphs
    p = bk.figure()
    for case in src.data.keys():
        if case != "index":
            p.line(source = src, x = 'index', y = case, color = dict_colors[case])  
            print("plotting loop")


    def update(attr,old,new):
    #Callback    
        print("update triggered")
        selection = list()

        for i in wg_chk.active:
            selection.append(data_list[i])

        src = make_data(selection)

        print(selection)


    wg_chk = CheckboxGroup(labels = data_list, active = [0]*len(data_list))        
    wg_chk.on_change('active', update) 

    layout = ly.row(wg_chk,p)
    doc.add_root(layout)

bk.show(modify_doc, notebook_url='localhost:8888')
```

**UPDATE #1**

I changed the code in the callback to make the appropriate dataframe, then create a dict using ColumnDataSource.from_df, then set src.data equal to it as below. Still doesn't seem to work. I used a print to make sure data_new has correct keys.

```
df_new = make_df(selection)
data_new = md.ColumnDataSource.from_df(df_new)
src.data = data_new
```

For clarity, I am using the newest version of Bokeh and Python as of today (Bokeh 1.0.2, Python 3.7.1)

**UPDATE #2**

As per the comments, I pre-generated all the required glyphs ahead of time, so they are, in essence, "slots for data" instead of being generated on demand for any amount of datasets. As they are now persistent, this allows me to toggle them on/off with the .visible property easily. I now have six "slots" for data to be plotted with corresponding glyphs, and I added a function within the callback to update their respective data sources (in this case, changing a linear to a quadratic curve). I also updated Bokeh to the newest version (1.3.4). Note that this is specifically embeddable in a Jupyter Notebook.

Here is the code for reference:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bk
import bokeh.layouts as ly
import bokeh.models as md
import bokeh.colors as cl
import bokeh.palettes as plet

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.io import show as io_show
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Select, Button, RadioGroup
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, show, figure, output_notebook, reset_output, curdoc

data_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
data_list2 = ["one", "two"]
data_fac = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
data_fac_dict = dict(zip(data_list,data_fac))
data_x = np.linspace(0,100)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = data_list)
for case in data_list:
    df[case] = data_x * data_fac_dict[case] + np.power(data_x, 3) * data_fac_dict[case]

def modify_doc(doc):

    #Make colors
    list_colors = plet.Dark2[len(data_list)]
    dict_colors = dict(zip(data_list,list_colors))


    p = bk.figure()

    def make_line(case):
        line = p.line(x = 'index', y = case, source = src_store[case], color = dict_colors[case])
        return line

    #Make six sources, make one line per source, and set them to invisible
    src_store = dict()
    list_lines = dict()

    for case in data_list:
        src_store[case] = md.ColumnDataSource(df[[case]])
        list_lines[case] = make_line(case)
        list_lines[case].visible = False

    #First checkbox defaults to ticked, so let's show it by default.
    list_lines["one"].visible = True

    def modify_data(order):
    #Modify the data and update the six sources' data with it
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns = data_list)
        src_store_new = dict()
        data_new = dict()

        for case in data_list:
            df[case] = data_x * data_fac_dict[case] + np.power(data_x,order) * data_fac_dict[case]
            data_new[case] = md.ColumnDataSource.from_df(df[[case]])
            src_store[case].data = data_new[case]

    def update(attr,old,new):
    #Callback    
        print("update triggered")

        #Get selection of lines to display
        selection = list()
        for i in wg_chk.active:
            selection.append(data_list[i])

        #Set visibility according to selection
        for case in data_list:
            list_lines[case].visible = case in selection

        #Get line multiplier from radio buttons and update sources
        order = wg_rad.active + 1
        modify_data(order)

        print(selection)

    wg_rad = RadioGroup(labels=["x*0", "x*1"], active = 0)
    wg_chk = CheckboxGroup(labels = data_list, active = [0]*len(data_list))

    wg_chk.on_change('active', update)
    wg_rad.on_change('active', update)

    layout = ly.row(ly.column(wg_chk,wg_rad),p)
    doc.add_root(layout)

bk.show(modify_doc, notebook_url='localhost:8888')
```

Comment: FYI 1.0.2 is almost a year old. The newest version of Bokeh today is 1.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you plot a Bokeh glyph, that glyph object has an associated data source. If you want the glyph to update, you need to update *that existing datasource*, i.e. modify it by setting it's `.data` property. The code above does not do that. It creates a *new* data source, that is not attached to or configured on anything, and then immediate throws it away (it's a local variable in a function, since nothing keeps a reference to it, it disappears when the function finishes).

You need to update whatever existing data source that you used initially:

```
source.data = new_data  # plain python dict
```

And, at least as of Bokeh 1.3.4 `new_data` must be a ***plain Python dictionary***. It is not supported to "migrate" a `.data` value from one CDS to another:

```
source1.data = source2.data  # BAD! WILL NOT WORK
```

Attempting to do so will probably raise an explicit error in the near future. There is a `from_df` static method on `ColumnDataSource` you can use to convert DataFrames to the right kind of `dict`.

Comment: Thank you - I saw you replying to another post with a similar issue, but I couldn't follow the resolution.

I tried what you suggested, but couldn't make it work - see edit on main post.

Comment: Glyphs are configured to look at specific columns in a CDS. You are only ever adding one line glyph, which is only ever configure to look at the "one" column. Adding new columns will have no effect, because you never make any glyphs to look at those columns. It seems like you should create one CDS for all the data, and glyphs for every column up front, then use the callback to merely toggle which ones are visible. That will be much simpler. See e.g https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/line_on_off.py

Comment: Thank you - also for the tip about the Bokeh version, I clearly missed something there. Now on the latest version. I will try your suggestion tomorrow. I think I am misunderstanding something fundamental with callbacks - I assumed that if a source changes, part of the code will be re-run. On that basis I thought I would have new glyphs created. Could you explain what exactly is changed or re-run once you have a callback? For example, if I make glyphs in a callback, can they ever be added to the plot? If the source can be updated outside a callback, how come other code doesn't follow?

Comment: You can add/remove glyphs in callbacks (though I generally advise to avoid it, if possible, since updating *data* is the best practice). However, your `update` callback above, which is the only code that is executed when the checkbox `active` state changes, does not add or delete any glyphs. The only things that are executed in response to events or property changes are the callbacks you choose to specify with `on_change` or `on_event`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I implemented both pre-generating all required glyphs and then toggling invisibility and updating sources with the from_df method, and it all works beautifully.. I will update the post for reference.